# How to show a bootstrap popup modal in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to open popup a modal on resource page using java-script or predefined function in laravel.

Comment: you can use https://getbootstrap.com/ or https://bulma.io/ or other frameworks which provide Modal components which can be activated as you want them. You should just be able to do a little Javascript to do that in case you use bulma. Bootstrap on the other hand has a different approach which might be easier, but it is a heavier framework.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck. Please ask a _question_ (this isn't a question) when you actually have a problem you'd like help with. Right now it sounds like you just need to do some research.

Answer (score 6):

may be,

you have want to open pop up using js in blade template so for that

add the button in the blade file and before that add bootstrap.css file in it.

```
<button type="submit"  class="donate_now btn btn-default-border-blk generalDonation" data-toggle="modal"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModalHorizontal">donate now</button>
```

Design modal according that like this in same page

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalHorizontal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header" style="background: orange">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ion-android-close"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color: whitesmoke;">Donation For Siddhyog Sadhan Mandal</h4>
        </div>            <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
                Payment Option
            </div>
            <form id="frm-donation" name="frm-donation">
                <div class="header-btn">
                    <div id="div-physical">
                        <label>
                            <input id="rdb_physical" name="rdb_donation" value="0" type="radio" checked="" class="validate[required]" data-errormessage-value-missing="Donation Type is required!">
                            Physical Entity Donation
                        </label>
                    </div>
            </form>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-footer" id="modal_footer">
                    <!--<input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Donate" class="btn btn-default-border-blk" type="submit">-->
                    <a id="btnDonate" class="btn btn-default-border-blk">Donate</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you can see the modal work on page but for that make sure about ID on data-target="#myModalHorizontal" and modal's id id="myModalHorizontal"